# Python Tkinter. Cant apply theme for second window of program

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, themes

I am trying to make basic gui with Tkinter. But the default theme "Motif" is not pretty so I`ve switched to "Clam". But the problem in second window of my program, it still uses default theme "Motif".

Let me show at first my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


def label(row, column, text):
    L = Label(root, text=text, anchor='w')
    L.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nw",pady=2,padx=3)


def button(root, row, column, text, command):
    B = Button(root, text=text, command=command, width=15)
    B.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="e", pady=4, padx=3)


def entry(row, column, insert="", show=""):
    E = Entry(root, width=32)
    E.insert(0, insert)
    E.config(show=show)
    E.grid(row=row,column=column)
    return E


def show_ldif():

    values_list = []
    givenname = var0.get()
    sn = var1.get()
    country = var2.get()
    location = var3.get()
    skype = var8.get()

    cn = givenname[0].lower() + sn.lower()
    email = cn + "@company.com"   

    # ldif is import format for openLDAP
    ldif_list =[]
    ldif_list.append(("dn: cn=%s,cn=people,ou=company,dc=company,dc=com\n") % cn)
    ldif_list.append('c: %s\n'% country)
    ldif_list.append('cn: %s\n'% cn)
    ldif_list.append(('objectclass: inetOrgPerson\n'
                      'objectclass: posixAccount\n'
                      'objectclass: top\n'
                      'objectclass: shadowAccount\n'
                      'objectclass: ldapPublicKey\n'
                      'objectclass: extensibleObject\n'))

    ldif = ''.join(ldif_list)

    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("Result")
    root2.style = Style()
    root2.style.theme_use("clam")


    ldif_text = Text(root2, height=30, width=50)
    ldif_text.insert(END, ldif)
    ldif_text.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 2)

    button(root2, 1, 1, "Copy to Clipboard", yes_no)
    button(root2, 1, 0, "Import to LDAP", yes_no)


def yes_no():
    pass


root = Tk()

root.style = Style()
root.style.theme_use("clam")

root.title("LDAP Adder")

label(0, 0, 'First name')
var0 = entry(0, 1)

label(1, 0, 'Second name')
var1 = entry(1, 1)

label(2, 0, 'Country (two letters)')
var2 = entry(2, 1)

label(3, 0, 'City')
var3 = entry(3, 1)

label(8, 0, 'Skype')
var8 = entry(8, 1)

label(13, 0, '')

button(root, 14, 0, 'Show', show_ldif)
button(root, 14, 1, 'Quit', root.quit)

root.mainloop()
```

First window looks well:

[image]

It is Calm theme for Tkinter. Then I can click on button 'Show' and second window 'Result' will appear:

[image]

But second one still uses default theme (look at buttons of right window). But why? I`ve activated "Calm" theme for second window:

```
root2 = Tk()
root2.title("Result")
root2.style = Style()
root2.style.theme_use("clam")
```

Comment: Do not use 2 instance of `Tk`. Use a [_`Toplevel`_](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widget for the second window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With such code looks good:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


def label(row, column, text):
    L = Label(root, text=text, anchor='w')
    L.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nw",pady=2,padx=3)


def button(root, row, column, text, command):
    B = Button(root, text=text, command=command, width=15)
    B.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="e", pady=4, padx=3)


def entry(row, column, insert="", show=""):
    E = Entry(root, width=32)
    E.insert(0, insert)
    E.config(show=show)
    E.grid(row=row,column=column)
    return E


def show_ldif():

    values_list = []
    givenname = var0.get()
    sn = var1.get()
    country = var2.get()
    location = var3.get()
    skype = var8.get()

    cn = givenname[0].lower() + sn.lower()
    email = cn + "@company.com"   

    # ldif is import format for openLDAP
    ldif_list =[]
    ldif_list.append(("dn: cn=%s,cn=people,ou=company,dc=company,dc=com\n") % cn)
    ldif_list.append('c: %s\n'% country)
    ldif_list.append('cn: %s\n'% cn)
    ldif_list.append(('objectclass: inetOrgPerson\n'
                      'objectclass: posixAccount\n'
                      'objectclass: top\n'
                      'objectclass: shadowAccount\n'
                      'objectclass: ldapPublicKey\n'
                      'objectclass: extensibleObject\n'))

    ldif = ''.join(ldif_list)

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Result")

    ldif_text = Text(top, height=30, width=50)
    ldif_text.insert(END, ldif)
    ldif_text.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 2)

    button(top, 1, 1, "Copy to Clipboard", yes_no)
    button(top, 1, 0, "Import to LDAP", yes_no)


def yes_no():
    pass


root = Tk()

root.style = Style()
root.style.theme_use("clam")

root.title("LDAP Adder")

label(0, 0, 'First name')
var0 = entry(0, 1)

label(1, 0, 'Second name')
var1 = entry(1, 1)

label(2, 0, 'Country (two letters)')
var2 = entry(2, 1)

label(3, 0, 'City')
var3 = entry(3, 1)

label(8, 0, 'Skype')
var8 = entry(8, 1)

label(13, 0, '')

button(root, 14, 0, 'Show', show_ldif)
button(root, 14, 1, 'Quit', root.quit)

root.mainloop()
```

So before I have been creating new window with:

```
root2 = Tk()
root2.title("Result")
root2.style = Style()
root2.style.theme_use("clam")
```

And theme cant be applied. With @Rinzler help I changed this code to:

```
top = Toplevel()
top.title("Result")
```

And activated theme only once in the beginning.

Comment: What is it about your code that fixes the problem? Without any sort of description, we have to look at your code line-by-line looking for differences. Your answer would be more useful if you describe what the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are creating two instances of `Tk`. That is not how tkinter is designed to be used. You must create exactly one instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.